# CSS animation for width in collapsing item

Tags: css, css-transitions

Currently I have a simple div with a button and a div representing a box, with a collapsing behaviour. Clicking the link hides/displays the box.

Only the box has a fixed width and I'm trying to animate the shrinking of the parent object correctly but so far I've not had much success.

Here is a fiddle with the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7ndv4uf/3/

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const box = document.querySelector('#box');

btn.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    box.classList.toggle('d-none');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  
  max-width: 500px;
  
  transition: width 2s, height 2s linear;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  transition: width 2s, height 2s linear;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    <div id="box" class="box d-none"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried to add a transition to the parent element, as I understand that it is the one affected by the resizing, also to the box itself, but so far nothing works. Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: Simplified the code removing Bootstrap dependency to just a bare-bones examples

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a CSS animation on your #box element ?

```
  .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  
  max-width: 500px;
  
  transition: width 2s, height 2s linear;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: open;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}


@keyframes open {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }

  to {
  width: 500px;
  }
}
```

You can make a lot of cool effect, CSS animation are now well supported and it will rerun evrery time you display the div.